# How to prune bookmarks for/after hg pull?

Tags: mercurial, bookmarks

Is there an option for `hg pull` to **force-update** (non-forward) *all* bookmarks or even **prune** **all** bookmarks which are not present in the remote repository anymore?

By "pruning" I mean to get rid of local bookmarks which are not present in the remote repository anymore. Otherwise, local bookmarks would constantly accumulate even they are already obsolete.

Put it with other words, I would like to work with bookmarks as I would work with Git (remote) refs.

If there is no built-in way to do this, what is the recommended sequence of commands to perform these tasks?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not entirely clear, so I'm taking a bit of a guess here. Bookmarks will normally be updated during a pull, unless they were changed to point to an earlier revision. In this case, you can use `hg pull -B <bookmarkname>` to pull a bookmark, anyway.

If by pruning bookmarks you mean deleting them from the remote server, you first have to delete them locally, then push the deleted bookmark. I.e.

```
hg bookmark -d <bookmarkname>
hg push -B <bookmarkname> <repository>
```

---

The easiest way to get rid of *all* bookmarks that don't exist on the remote repository is to first delete all inactive ones, and then pull from the repository again.

Example:

```
hg bookmark -d $(hg bookmarks | awk '{if (NF == 2) print $1;}')
hg pull
```

You can put the first command in your `.hgrc` file as an alias, e.g.:

```
[alias]
clrbookmarks = !$HG bookmark -d $($HG bookmarks | awk '{if (NF == 2) print $$1;}')
```